# No overload for 'mysql' matches delegate 'ElapsedEventHandler'. Windows Service C#

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have developed a windows service for copying a file from one location to another.

Since I need to run the service in the background there is a necessity of implementing a timer function.

**Service.cs**

```
  protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            //OnStart(new string[0]);


        }


        public void Start()
        {

            timer1 = new Timer();
            this.timer1.Interval = 30000; //every 30 seconds
           41 ***this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.mysql);***
            timer1.Enabled = true;
           43 mysql();
        }

        static void mysql()
        {
             **File copy code included in this function.
         }
```

The error triggers in line 41 mentioned above and is,

> No overload for 'mysql' matches delegate 'ElapsedEventHandler'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set param on mysql() like this

```
static void mysql(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
```

I hope it works for you :)

++ added via comment

this code will allows timer work with interval

add this code in Start()

```
        this.timer1.Interval = 1000;
        this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.mysql_tick);
```

and add this code out of Start()

```
private void mysql_tick( object sender, EventArgs e ){
blah blah... }
```

++ after that you need to use timer1.Start(); for work with mysql_tick

++ timer1.Stop(); will halt work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this will leads to another error "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'sender' of 'Service1.mysql(object, ElapsedEventArgs)" in line 43 (above code) @Arphile

Comment: you need to set mysql(); 's param also.
it'll work as mysql(null, null); because you'll not use sender and e

Comment: Would you mind me telling how to set the mysql() parameters, please! @Arphile

Comment: mysql(null, null); will work.
if you don't want to use null for calling, try edit method like this.
static void mysql(object sender = null, ElapsedEventArgs e = null )
if then, mysql(); will work

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked finally. One more thing although there were no compile errors the program won't run in the background. It outputs the correct file but I need to run this in the background since the file needs to be moved in every 5 minutes. That's the reason for implementing a Timer function. Do you have any clue why it starts and stop? @Arphile

Comment: on VisualStudio's Form editor, it makes Tick EventHandler.
I'll post code under my answer.